# How to override base method in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I want to create custom Textbox control in asp.net.But i have one doubt when i override the base method i got predefined syntax something like this

```
 base.OnRender(writer);
```

Now my question is that from where I should  start witting the code means before Base.OnRender or after base.OnRender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you **don't** want the base class behavior to occur at all, you should delete the line.

Whether you should write your code before, after or in between depends on the semantics of the call and method (that is, what the base method does and what you *want* to do in the overriden method).

For example, if you want to inject HTML *before* the HTML of the base class, you will add your code before. If after, you would write your code after. If you want to *wrap* the HTML in yours, you would write code before *and* after.

Answer (score 0):

normally , after base.OnRender.

Base methods should only be included if you want to inherit your base method behaviour and if it the case than you should start your overridden code after calling to the base method.

But this is not necessary but most logical and desriable.

Answer (score 0):

The first line in your custom control's `OnRender` method would be `base.OnRender(writer);`.

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: My question is that from where I should start writing the code i.e. before base.OnRender(writer) or after base.Onrender and why?

Comment: see Oded's reply. It is not a hard and fast rule as it depends on what you wish to achieve..